# Ajustar imagens HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site de loja de roupas e a primeira imagem está muito colada na tela e o segundo texto da 3 imagem está atrás da imagem help

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/Shop.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.newarrival {
  background: rgb(203, 117, 224);
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.col-md-7 h2 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.stars {
  height: 25px;
}
.price {
  color: #6ffe0f;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid rgb(7, 6, 6);
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 33px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  outline: none;
}
.cart {
  background: #ff9011;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.cart:hover {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.carousel-item img {
  border: 10px solid #e712e7;
}
img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(119, 218, 38);
}
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

DIV.container {
  min-height: 14em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right p {
  position: absolute;

  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}
text-align: left;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Loja virtual</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="roupas loja.css">
  </body>

</html>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>

<!--- aqui fica toda a escrita em baixo da imagem --->
<!---tem o botão comprar que o primeiro funciona e o segundo não fica verde quando passa o mouse encima como resolver? help --->
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
  <p class="price"> BR R$ 34,90
  <p>
    <b>
      <p>A venda: camisa xadrez
      <p> </br>
      <p> TAMANHOS: P, G, M
      <p>
      <p> P veste 36/38
      <p>
      <p>M veste 40
      <p>
      <p>G veste 42
      <p>
        <label> Quantidade: </label>
        <input type="text" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="btn-default cart">Comprar</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<body>
  <html>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      padding-right: 40px;
    }

    * {
      position: relative;
      width: 300;
    }

    .fora {
      display: inline;
    }

    .example-item_first {
      background-color: #FAA116;
    }

    .fora img {
      width: 500;
    }

    .fora p {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 90%;
    }
  </style>

  </style>
  <div class=fora>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQv3klyi5GqnkYhQqaWEvqlxP65sKPij7nbVg&usqp=CAU.jpg'>
  </div>
  <div class=fora>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFTtVBY-Wy5EVwtpI4wCNn9WPmT7_Q8K5T3A&usqp=CAU.jpg'>
  </div>
  <div class=fora>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdH-DasPvknFgGtM8NfKT5wQb_oxLKL6Yr6f7By8RVklkXbuDsSUEyWjYBEt3eZL7VTew&usqp=CAU.jpg'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<div class="col-md-7">
  <p class="price">BR R$ 44,90
  <p>
    <b>
      <p>A venda: Calça cargo preta
      <p> </br>
      <p> TAMANHOS: P, G, M
      <p>
      <p> P veste 36/38
      <p>
      <p>M veste 40
      <p>
      <p>G veste 42
      <p>
        <label> Quantidade: </label>
        <input type="text" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="btn-default cart">Comprar</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<body>

  <html>

  </html>
```

Answer (score -3):

O erro é consertado colocando um `margin-top` para 50px ou 55px (neste caso) e retirei o `transform`, também coloquei uns estilos básicos, o código está pronto para usar:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button,a{
cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
 background: url(../img/Shop.jpg); /* ERROR: No file found */
 /* background: #fff; */
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
 
}

.newarrival {
  background: rgb(203, 117, 224);
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.col-md-7 h2 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.stars {
  height: 25px;
}
.price {
  color: #6ffe0f;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid rgb(7, 6, 6);
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 33px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  outline: none;
}
.cart {
  background: #ff9011;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.cart:hover {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.carousel-item img {
  border: 10px solid #e712e7;
}
img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(119, 218, 38);
}
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

div.container {
  min-height: 14em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right p {
  position: absolute;

  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}

.margin14424{
  margin-top: 55px; /* problema resolvido */
  left: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Loja Virtual</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
               <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                     <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-7">
            <p class="price"> BR R$ 34,90
            <p>
            <div class="margin14424">
               <b>
               <p>A venda: camisa xadrez
               <p> </br>
               <p> TAMANHOS: P, G, M
               <p>
               <p> P veste 36/38
               <p>
               <p>M veste 40
               <p>
               <p>G veste 42
               <p>
                  <label> Quantidade: </label>
                  <input type="text" value="1">
                  <button type="button" class="btn-default cart">Comprar</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <body>
         <html>
            <style>
               ul {
               list-style: none;
               display: flex;
               padding-right: 40px;
               }
               * {
               position: relative;
               width: 300;
               }
               .fora {
               display: inline;
               }
               .example-item_first {
               background-color: #FAA116;
               }
               .fora img {
               width: 500;
               }
               .fora p {
               position: absolute;
               bottom: 0;
               width: 90%;
               }
            </style>
            </style>
            <div class=fora>
               <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQv3klyi5GqnkYhQqaWEvqlxP65sKPij7nbVg&usqp=CAU.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class=fora>
               <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFTtVBY-Wy5EVwtpI4wCNn9WPmT7_Q8K5T3A&usqp=CAU.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class=fora>
               <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdH-DasPvknFgGtM8NfKT5wQb_oxLKL6Yr6f7By8RVklkXbuDsSUEyWjYBEt3eZL7VTew&usqp=CAU.jpg'>
            </div>
            </body>
         </html>
         <div class="col-md-7">
            <p class="price">BR R$ 44,90
            <p>
               <b>
            <p>A venda: Calça cargo preta
            <p> </br>
            <p> TAMANHOS: P, G, M
            <p>
            <p> P veste 36/38
            <p>
            <p>M veste 40
            <p>
            <p>G veste 42
            <p>
               <label> Quantidade: </label>
               <input type="text" value="1">
               <button type="button" class="btn-default cart">Comprar</button>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </body>
</html>
```

Tente executar no [W3Schools Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/).

Comment: Muitooo Obrigadaaa meu Anjo. Vc é Incrível. Me ajudou muito :)